# get # String parameter from url

Tags: facebook-graph-api, struts2

how can I get certain parameter from url directly from struts2?

http://apps.facebook.com/testApp/myaction.action#param1=a1afacf5&param2=AAADpzov7PBMBA

Previously, getting param1 and 2 from javascripts in JSP using `window.location.href.slice`. Now I want to get those params directly from action class. I tried to get those using `request.getParameter("param1")`, but getting null.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to create property in your action class and provide there getter and setters,once this is done framework will push them in to the ValueStack with action processing.

OGNL expression will help you to access the properties being there in the Value-Stack.You have to do something like

### Action Class

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

   private String param1;
   private Sting param2;
   // provide getter and setters for the above properties

   public String execute() throws Exception{

      // your action logic and provide param1,param2 values which you want in you JSP
      return SUCCESS;

       }

}
```

once you action get called both the parameters will be pushed to value stack with the values you have provided in the action class,all you need to access them in your JSP with OGNL like

### JSP page

```
<s:property name="param1" value="param1"/>
<s:textfiled name="param2" value="%{param2}"/>
```